# When trying to utilize make patch, I get "fatal: ambiguous argument 'origin/master': unknown revision or path not in the working tree."

Tags: git, make

I've been scratching my head for this problem for a few good hours. For clarification, I am operating on a Ubuntu 20.04 (VM if it matters) and I encountered an error when trying to utilize the Makefile in the following way:

[image]

The error reads: `fatal: ambiguous argument 'origin/master': unknown revision or path not in the working tree. make: *** [Makefile:64: patch] Error 128`

As you can see, I have initialized a git repository before utilizing the make patch. I am lost; if there is anything else I can provide to clarify my issue even further or things that I can try, please let me know. Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: Is this what you are attempting: https://www.git-tower.com/learn/git/faq/create-and-apply-patch/

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't think that is what I want; I'm essentially trying to patch up my solution code with this Makefile. I had already finished writing the solution code (which works) and I am trying to patch it up to send.

Comment: Then you're using 'patch' in a way I'm not familiar with.